# Need something faster than mapply

Tags: r, function

I have this function which calculates correlation for lag varying from 1 to 1600.

```
t=min(length(x), length(y))
corf=function(i) {
            x=x[c(1:(t-i+1))]
            y=y[c(i:t)]
            cor(x,y, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
        }
```

Where x and y are the data sets containing around 10,000 values each.

```
lg=c(1:1600)
```

I have to find:

```
corf(lg)
```

For this I am using:

```
mapply(corf, lg)
```

But this is taking very long as I have 100 datasets.

Is there any alternative to `mapply` which faster?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I confess that I'm a bit puzzled. If `corf` only takes one (non-vectorized) argument, why are you using `mapply`?

Comment: @Chase- I have edited and provided t.

Comment: @joran- corf takes 'lg' which is vector. Therefore I'm using mapply.
simple corf(lg) is not working.

Comment: Can you construct a reproducible example?

Comment: I think you're confused about the differences between `mapply` and `lapply`/`sapply`. Also, as written, passing a vector to `corf` makes no sense, and indeed when you use `mapply`, `corf` is being sent only a single value at a time.

Comment: @joran- so, what would be better to use instead?

Comment: Could you not use `ccf()` to do this for you?

Comment: @GavinSimpson Although that might be what OP is after, ccf() gives far from the same result (it lags in both directions, so you get double of the information, and the outcome itself is slightly different as well as you work with an acf)

Comment: If you have a multicore CPU, you could try `parallel` package and its `mcmapply` (multicore mapply).