# Faster way than mapply function in R

Tags: r, mapply

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767043/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-from-a-column-inside-another-column-wit) for which I got a useful answer but the following code runs very slowly considering my big dataset (14K rows).

How can I make this faster using mcmapply like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026342/need-something-faster-than-mapply)?

this is the code:

```
within(df,
  count <- mapply(function(x, y) {
    in5year <- paste(animals.2[year %in% (x-4):x], collapse = "; ")
    sum(strsplit(in5year, "; ")[[1]] %in% strsplit(y, "; ")[[1]])
  }, year, animals.1)
)
```

Comment: Lots of things.  For one, why are you pasting values together only to split them up in the next line?

Comment: @thc, the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54767043/3358272) shows joining strings that already have embedded semi-colons, so effectively paste(c("cat;dog","bird"),collapse=";"). It does seem silly, but has its utility. Perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: @r2evans I see.  One small optimization is to perform strsplit on the entire vector before the loop; but that wasn't as much an increase as I thought it would be, so not really worth posting as an answer.  Multithreading (`mclapply`) works to speed things up as expected, but I can't find a significantly better baseline approach in R.  I think Rcpp would be needed to speed things up significantly.

Comment: I tried to use `mcmapply` but could not really write a working code. Could you share the code you developed with mcmapply please?

Comment: You only asked your first question today? Wait for people to answer on that thread before starting a new thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of occurrences of a string from a column inside another column, with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767043/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-from-a-column-inside-another-column-wit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using parallel.  Used `mclapply` instead of `mcmapply` as it was a little faster.

```
library(parallel)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

df = data.frame(animals.1 = c("cat; dog; bird", "dog; bird", "bird", "dog"), 
                animals.2 = c("cat; dog; bird","dog; bird; seal", "bird", ""), 
                stringsAsFactors = F)

df <- replicate(10000,{df}, simplify=F) %>% do.call(rbind, .)
df$year <- seq(2000,2000 + nrow(df) - 1)

st_func <- function(df) {
  within(df,
         count <- mapply(function(x, y) {
           in5year <- paste(animals.2[year %in% (x-4):x], collapse = "; ")
           sum(strsplit(in5year, "; ")[[1]] %in% strsplit(y, "; ")[[1]])
         }, year, animals.1)
  )
}

mc_func <- function(df) {
  df$count <- mclapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
    x <- df$year[i]
    y <- df$animals.1[i]
    in5year <- paste(df$animals.2[df$year %in% (x-4):x], collapse = "; ")
    sum(strsplit(in5year, "; ")[[1]] %in% strsplit(y, "; ")[[1]])
  }, mc.cores=4) %>% unlist
  return(df)
}

identical(mc_func(df), st_func(df)) # TRUE

microbenchmark(mc_func(df), st_func(df), times=5)

Unit: seconds
        expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
 mc_func(df)  8.588759  8.637135  9.101409  8.91779  8.924929 10.43843     5  a 
 st_func(df) 30.090307 30.107282 30.440877 30.45653 30.696706 30.85356     5   b
```